# How to get rid of Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release?

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04, nashorn

[image]I've seen dozens of posts showing how to get rid of this warning when using the Java 11 compiler. But in my case the warning simply appears each time I'm opening a terminal in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. So I really don't know how to deal with that as nowhere, when opening a terminal, the Java compiler is invoked. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on here ?
Kind regards,
Nicolas

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with the warning please?

Comment: Interesting, is it some special terminal? Why would it produce a warning specific to Java? And before the command prompt?

Comment: No, nothing of special, just the normal Gnome terminal. And why would it produce the warning ? I don't know, this is exactly my question.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is caused by running `jrunscript`.

`jrunscript` uses Nashorn which is deprecated in Java 11 and removed in Java 15. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)

As [@inof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11858083/inof) said in a comment:

> Nashorn is still maintained separately, and it can be installed as a separate package alongside Java. The only difference is that it’s not part of Java itself anymore, so it’s not installed automatically with the Java package.

You can suppress the warning by adding `-Dnashorn.args=--no-deprecation-warning` parameter to `jrunscript`.

Comment: Nashorn is not replaced by another engine. Nashorn is still maintained separately, and it can be installed as a separate package alongside Java. The only difference is that it’s not part of Java itself anymore, so it’s not installed automatically with the Java package.

Comment: Thanks @inof, I edited my answer with the text from your comment

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question. It appears that, in order to configure my JAVA_HOME I inserted this in my .bashrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));')"
```

This is what causes the nashorn warning each time I'm launching a terminal. I removed this from .bashrc and rather configured my JAVA_HOME in /etc/profile.d.

Kind regards,
Nicolas